# vs2008 Cannot read include file xxx.h Not enough space

Tags: visual-studio-2008

when I build a big solution, about 110 c++ projects, i got 200 errors like:

fatal error C1084: Cannot read include file: 'c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xxcallpmf': Not enough space
 Line 4237: 69>m:\main\3rdparty\boost_1_37_0\boost\detail\workaround.hpp : fatal error C1084: Cannot read include file: 'm:\main\3rdparty\boost_1_37_0\boost\detail\workaround.hpp': Not enough space
....
....
......

what's going on?

Windows 7 + 4G memory.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the partition that has your TMP and TEMP directories is nearly full, and in the middle of compiling the partition gets completely full.

Try creating a directory for yourself on some other partition that has lots of free space, set your environment variables TMP and TEMP to point to that directory, log out and log in again so your session uses those new settings, and try Visual Studio again.

Comment: the problem is te TMP/TEMP folder is on my C:/xxx/TEMP, and there are nearly 200GB free on the C:/, so is there a limit on the TEMP directory?

Comment: I haven't seen any limits on the TEMP directory.  If you have 200GB free on that partition then free space isn't the problem.  (Unless you have quotas set.)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are running out of space/quota on the drive that your TEMP (or TMP) environment variable points to.  if you start devenv from a command prompt try typing

```
set t
```

and see where these environment variables point to.  If you use an icon to start it, then you need to check the default environment.

- right click on "My Computer"
- choose "properties"
- if on Vista or Win7 click on "Advanced system settings" over in the right pane
- go to the "Advanced" tab
- click on the "Environment Variables..." button

Answer (score 0):

Not enough space might also be triggered by an exhaustion of the available number of `Inodes` (whatever they call it in `FAT/NTFS`), if you have many small files, and the maximum size of file list for that drive has been reached, even if there is still some available space.

I think some windows defragmenting tools allow to modify the `MFT` (Master file table) of `NTFS` partitions

Comment: Inodes are a UNIX thing, and simply do not exist on FAT/NTFS. Therefore neither of the two can run out of them.  You're right that NTFS uses a Master File Table, but unlike inodes that's not a finite resource. The exact reason why defragging tools can defrag the MFT is because the MFT can grow incrementally, and thus take up multiple fragments.